# Login Script does not function

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am having a slight problem with this login mechanism. It does not login the user on most conditions. if the user is new as in newly registered it works fine but then all other usernames are useless. The Login.php page is as follows :

```
<?php
//Disable error reporting 
error_reporting(0);
#Starting Session
session_start() ;
$_SESSION['username'] = 0 ;
$_SESSION['currentpage']="index.php" ;
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','SouravBasuRoy','2525','MyteraArt');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'] ;
$result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT `username`, `password` FROM Customers');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
if($row['username'] === $username && $row['password'] === $password)
{
$_SESSION['username']="$username";
setcookie('username' , $row['username']) ;
header("Location: http://localhost/loggedin.php") ;
}
else
{
header("Location: http://localhost/index.html") ;
}
}
?>
```

This is the script I am using for checking if user is logged in or not. I copy pasted this on all of my pages.

```
<?php
$username = $_COOKIE['username'] ;
if ($username =="")
{
echo '<form name="login" action="login.php" method="post">
<label>Login</label>
<label for="Username">Username :<input type="text" name="username"></label>
<label for="Password">Password :<input type="password" name="password"></label>
<input type="submit">
</form>' ;
}
else
{
echo '<form action="logout.php">Logged in as : ' . $_COOKIE["username"] . ' ' . '<input type="submit" value="Logout"></form>' ;
}
?>
```

The problem I am facing is it does not function properly breaking the script with

```
echo $row['username];
echo $row['password'] ;
```

displays the username and password form the row but it does not log in the user.

The database structure is:

1 ID       tinyint(4)
2 Name     tinytext
3 Email    tinytext
4 Contact  bigint(20)
5 City     tinytext
6 username varchar(16)
7 password varchar(16)
8 isadmin  tinyint(1)

Comment: You know cookies can be forged right? currently your checking a cookie for login status, also cookies are open to XSS attacks, which your not protecting from.

Comment: @LozCherone even worse is that the passwords seem to be raw pw in the database.... not hashed or salted or peppered :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this to say

```
SELECT `username`, `password` FROM Customers
```

to say this

```
SELECT `username`, `password` FROM Customers WHERE username = ?
```

or else it would give you all the users in the database... this is why your form is giving you problems... because it is checking the first user in the database...

---

The following is how I would change your code...

**Change this:**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT `username`, `password` FROM Customers');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
if($row['username'] === $username && $row['password'] === $password)
{
$_SESSION['username']="$username";
setcookie('username' , $row['username']) ;
header("Location: http://localhost/loggedin.php") ;
}
else
{
header("Location: http://localhost/index.html") ;
}
```

**to this:**

```
$query = 'SELECT `username`, `password` FROM Customers where username = ?';

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($get_username, $get_password);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
}

if($get_username === $username && $get_password === $password){
    $_SESSION['username']="$username";
    setcookie('username' , $row['username']) ;
    header("Location: http://localhost/loggedin.php");
    exit();
} else {
    header("Location: http://localhost/index.html");
    exit();
}
```

---

There is a big flaw with the way you are handling passwords in the database... they should not be raw passwords... please hash them, with a salt and maybe even a pepper.

Comment: @Whistler81 make sure you hash your passwords in the database... and cookies can also be accessed and changed through any decent browser

Comment: thanks for the tip, actually this is just a college project so I am not so concerned about that. but will surely research that for future projects(if I make it that is).

Comment: @Whistler81 you must create a new question, because thats out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Hi @Arian I am facing another issue with this code, the else part is not firing. If I enter wrong username password combination it does not take me to the index.html page but gives me a blank login.php page.